# How many subgroups of order 5 does $S_5$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that $|S_5|= 5!$ and it's obvious that $5\mid5!$ but how much such subgroups exist?
I know I can use Lagrange's theorem somehow but I don't know how.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: One cannot use Lagrange's Theorem alone. While it is true that if $H \le G$, then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$, the converse is not necessarily true; i.e. there need not exist a subgroup of order $d$ for any divisor $d$ of the total group order $|G|$.

Comment: Upto isomorphie, the only group with order $5$ is the cyclic group $Z_5$

Comment: Thanks for the early response but what can I use to find the number of subgroups of order 5?

Answer (score 7):

A subgroup of order $5$ is necessarily cyclic (because $5$ is prime). Observe that

- Each subgroup of order $5$ consists of the identity element, and four elements of order $5$.
- Every element of order $5$ generates a subgroup of order $5$.

So, once you figure out how many elements there are of order $5$, divide that answer by $4$ to get the number of subgroups of order $5$.

As for the elements of order $5$, I'll point out that the $5$-cycles, e.g. $(12534)$, are obvious examples, but you should figure out if there are any other elements of order $5$, and also be sure to count them all correctly, because e.g. $(12534)=(25341)$.

Comment: My guess is that'd be (5!/5)=24?
So answer is 6?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have a proof that there are no other elements of order $5$. It would probably be good practice for you to figure out what the subgroups are explicitly.